# Transfer Everything to Another Player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I am running a Bukkit server on my local machine for personal use with MultiVerse plugin.  Last week, my Internet went down for a couple of days, so I thought I could just play in offline mode on a new world I setup.  Now that my Internet is back up, I wanted to continue playing in that world.  However, my inventory, XP, etc. is now all bound to `player`, which is the default username if you're not logged in.  How can I easily move everything from `player` back to my real user, `mellamokb`?

Comment: Are there any permissions plugins or anything that might be at work?  If not, honestly the simplest thing might just be to drop it all in a chest offline then log back on.

Comment: @Shinrai: That is actually what I ended up doing :)

Answer (score 5):

You can try to go to `<minecraft_data>/saves/<map_name>/players` and rename `Player.dat` to `<your_name>.dat`. This should effectively transfer your inventory, spawn points, xp, hunger bar and so on to another player.

However I don't think you will be able to transfer ownership ("tamer") of cats and wolves with this way. They are likely to be stored in the entity NBT tags. You can try to use MCEdit if you need to change the owner of them.

P.S. `<minecraft_data>` is usually `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft`.

Also, always make a backup before messing with anything.